# iOS ReplayKit stop recording microphone if i play AVPlayer during recording

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

i am using ReplayKit's `RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture` method to record screen and microphone, but i am facing an issue. if i play AVPlayer while ScreenRecording, the microphone stops recording audio.  Below are two scenario. in first everything working fine but in second voice recording not working.

1. started AVPlayer and then start screenRecording, AVPlayer's Audio stop and my screen and microphone start recording
2. started screenRecording and working fine. then i start the AVPlayer and when AVPlayer play the audio the voice recording is stopped

Comment: capturing audio from the microphone isn't working when we remove the application from the stack, any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by remove application from from stack ?, do you exiting application?

Comment: I mean to say once I kill the application screen recording is working fine but recording audio stops. but very first time when I install the application Everything is working fine.

Comment: did you find a working solution for this scenario? as I'm using the same repository which you've created on Git: https://github.com/Ajaysainisd/ScreenRecorderWithAudio

Comment: ok, how you can record the screen when you killed the application ?

Comment: open application second time and audio from microphone won't get captured, please check your repo I've submitted an issue with regeneration steps.

Comment: Please check your mute key and i have updated the answer here, please follow it

Comment: tried the same but didn't work. same output, second-time Audio isn't getting recorded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging a lot i found a solution. Default `AVFoundation` Allow to use either Microphone or Speaker at a time and ReplayKit is incompatible with AVPlayer content. So if we want to use both of them at a time we need to set `AVAudioSession`'s Category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute`.

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a system limitation
As in apple official documents it is written

> ReplayKit is incompatible with AVPlayer content.

You can read details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit?language=objc)

Comment: Ok i got it. but i just want to prevent the AVPlayer to play the audio. just like when i start recording using replyKit. it mute the AVPlayer and start recording. i just want to do the same with AVPlayer if the AVPlayer play after starting the screenRecording

Comment: to mute AVplayer, you can use its isMuted property before starting the recording. I don't know if it works, but it worths a try.

Comment: but i found a solution for doing this